# Помогите перенести функции приложения в один файл, а графический интерфейс в другой Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

Помогите перенести функции приложения в один файл, а графический интерфейс в другой.

Мне необходимо оставить построение графического интерфейса в файле `mainwindow.py` , а функции и методы логики приложения перенести в файл `main.py`. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Файл **main.py**:

```
import sys

from mainwindow import *

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Файл **mainwindow.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia as M
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 221, 21))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "play"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "pause"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open File"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.play)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.pause)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.choose)
        self.player = M.QMediaPlayer()

    def play(self):
        url = self.url.toString().split('/')
        name = url[-1]

        self.label.setText(name)
        self.player.play()


    def pause(self):
        self.player.pause()
    def choose(self):
        self.url, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'OpenFile', './', 'Music (*.mp3 *.wav)' )

        self.url = QUrl(self.url)

        self.content = M.QMediaContent(self.url)
        self.player.setMedia(self.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно это делается так:

**main_q1217115.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog 
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl          
from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia as M 
from mainwindow_q1217115 import Ui_MainWindow                 # + Ui_MainWindow


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.url = None
        self.player = M.QMediaPlayer()
        
    def play(self):
        if self.url:                                             # !!!
            self.player.play()

    def pause(self):
        if self.url:                                             # !!!
            self.player.pause()
        
    def choose(self):
        self.url, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            None, 'OpenFile', './', 'Music (*.mp3 *.wav)' 
        )
        if not self.url:                                         # !!!
            self.label.setText('')
            return
        self.url = QUrl(self.url)
        self.content = M.QMediaContent(self.url)
        self.player.setMedia(self.content)
        self.label.setText(self.url.toString().split('/')[-1])
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**mainwindow_q1217115.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 221, 21))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "play"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "pause"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open File"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.play)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.pause)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.choose)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: почему именно `main_q1217115`?

Comment: @Danis имена модулей делайте какие вам нравятся. Имена, которые предложил автор у меня уже заняты :)

Comment: @Дмитрий что не так?

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас верно понял, под словами *функции и методы логики приложения* Вы имеете в виду методы `play(self)`, `pause(self)` и `choose(self)`.

Тогда всё зависит от того, где Вы хотите поместить объявление класса. Я перепишу Ваш код так, чтобы объявление класса осталось в main.py. Тогда будет вот так:

main.py:

```python
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    from mainwindow import setupUi
    from mainwindow import retranslateUi

    def play(self):
        url = self.url.toString().split('/')
        name = url[-1]

        self.label.setText(name)
        self.player.play()


    def pause(self):
        self.player.pause()
    def choose(self):
        self.url, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'OpenFile', './', 'Music (*.mp3 *.wav)' )

        self.url = QUrl(self.url)

        self.content = M.QMediaContent(self.url)
        self.player.setMedia(self.content)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

mainwindow.py:

```python
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia as M
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 40, 75, 23))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 40, 75, 23))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 75, 23))
    self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 221, 21))
    self.label.setText("")
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 20))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "play"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "pause"))
    self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open File"))
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.play)
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.pause)
    self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.choose)
    self.player = M.QMediaPlayer()
```

К сожалению, у меня нет PyQt и нет возможности проверить работоспособность данного кода, а потому, на всякий случай, приведу пример, как объявлять методы класса отдельно от самого класса в общем виде. Допустим, есть класс `X`, у него методы `y` и `z`. Первый объявлен в самом классе, а второй в отдельном файле. Тогда файлы примут следующий вид:

main.py:

```python
class X:
    from some_file import z    

    def y(self):
        pass

if __name__ == 'main':
    x = X()
    x.y() # Будет работать, т.к. объявлено прямо в классе
    x.z() # Тоже будет работать, т.к. импортировано в класс из другого файла
```

some_file.py:

```pyton
def z(self):
    pass
```

P.S. Ответ написан по мотивам [этого](https://issue.life/questions/47561840) ответа.